# Array to string conversion fwrite php

Tags: php, fwrite

Good day!

I am trying to print the array on the text file but whenever I try to run my code, I would always get this error

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in <path>
```

It would point to this line of code:

```
fwrite($listonedupe, $result1.PHP_EOL);
```

What could be the possible solution for this?

```
<?php

$getapps = 'B:\z.test\runningapps.txt';
$fordupe = 'B:\z.test\fordupe.txt';
$sendtoserver = 'B:\z.test\sendtoserver.txt';

if ($file1 = fopen($getapps, "r"))
{
    $read1 = fread($file1,filesize($getapps));
    $line1 = explode("\n", $read1);

    $file2 = fopen($fordupe, "r");
    $read2 = fread($file2,filesize($fordupe));
    $line2 = explode("\n", $read2);

    $result1 = array_diff($line1, $line2);

    if (count($result1)>0)
    {
        $forserver = fopen($sendtoserver,"w");
        foreach ($result1 as $value1) {
        fwrite($forserver, $value1.PHP_EOL);

            // for checking server
            $s1 = fopen($sendtoserver, "r");
            $s2 = fread($s1,filesize($sendtoserver));
            $s3 = explode("\n", $s2);
            var_dump($s3);

        $listonedupe = fopen($fordupe,"a");
        fwrite($listonedupe, $result1.PHP_EOL);
        }

        // for checking dupe
        var_dump($line2);
    }
    else
        echo "ok";
}else
     die("Unable to open file!");

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `fwrite($listonedupe, $result1.PHP_EOL);` to `fwrite($listonedupe, $value1.PHP_EOL);`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply sir! It works! thank you!